# Call Python function from Matlab which uses global variables previously defined in Python environment

Tags: python, matlab, global-variables

I'm trying to call from Matlab a custom function that references variables previously defined in Python.

The sequence of the events is as follows:

1. Define variables in Python, including a function (fminconMaster_py) that uses 2 anonymous functions that takes 'x' as argument (fun_py, obj_py)
2. Call a Matlab function (optim_mat) that uses fmincon algorithm for an optimization problem - that optimization problem has 2 anonymous functions (fun_mat, obj_mat) defined in Matlab (objective and constraints)
3. Whenever Matlab objective and constraints anonymous functions (fun_mat, obj_mat) are called by fmincon routine, they point to a matlab function (fupdate) that calls on fminconMaster_py, which in turn references to the python anonymous function fun_py and obj_py

The problem is that when 3 happens, fminconMaster_py defined in Python doesn't recognize fun_py and obj_py ("Python Error: NameError: name xxx not defined")

See code below

Python code for fminconMaster_py (calling fun_py and obj_py)

```
def fminconMaster_py(x):

    validNonLinearUpperConstraint =  Cu != np.Inf
    validNonLinearLowerConstraint = Cl != -np.Inf

    nonLinearUpperConstraint = Cu[validNonLinearUpperConstraint]
    nonLinearLowerConstraint = Cl[validNonLinearLowerConstraint]

    cUpper = fun_py (x)[validNonLinearUpperConstraint] - nonLinearUpperConstraint
    cLower = nonLinearLowerConstraint - fun_py (x)[validNonLinearLowerConstraint]

    c= np.vstack(cUpper, cLower)   
    obj = obj_py(x)

    return obj, c
```

Matlab code for fupdate

```
pyfunction='pythonModule.fminconMaster_py' 

function [J, cin, gJ, gcin] = fupdate(x)
    eval(['output = py.', pyfunction, '(x);'])  
    ...
end
```

The error occurs when fupdate evaluates the expression because some variables are not defined in fminconMaster_py (Cu, Cl, fun_py, obj_py). See error pasted below

```
Python Error: NameError: name 'Cu' is not defined

Error in optimize/obj (line 69)
    [J, cin, gJ, gcin] = fupdate(x);

Error in fmincon (line 546)
  initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});

Error in optimize (line 34)
[xopt, fopt, exitflag, optoutput] = fmincon(@obj, x0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub, @con, opt);

Caused by:
Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.
```

I could pass Cu and Cl as arguments as they are arrays but fun_py and obj_py are complex functions that I built in Python

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass them into the function.

You can't do this by magic; Python doesn't share a namespace with any part of MATLAB - in fact, Python namespaces are module-specific. You'll have to pass them in, causing them to be converted from one language's representation to the other's.

---

What you *can* do is define a function that loads variables into the Python module's global namespace. Something like:

```
def load_globals_py(d):
    globals().update(d)
```

This function will take a dictionary, where the keys are variable names, and add those to the module's global namespace. You can call this from MATLAB before you run your other functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response

I understand that Python doesn't share anything with Matlab but I believe that by calling py.modulename.fminconMaster_py(x), I am not asking Matlab to evaluate anything that is Python related, rather I am calling on Python to do its own work with its environment (and therefore was hoping it could access fun_py and obj_py defined there)

In fact, the only thing I am passing to my Python function is 'x' and that's fine. Unfortunately, I can't pass fun_py and obj_py from Matlab as they are complex function that I can't replicate in Matlab

Comment: @blouvard You _could_ pass them into a different function that sets the global variables in the Python namespace... but I don't know how clean that would be.

Comment: thanks again - and how would you do that? I mean calling a python function in Matlab that takes fun_py and obj_py as argument? How could this function set them as global variables in the namespace?